# Is a sealant needed in addition to caulking?

Tags: repair, sink, caulking

I've read on some forums (not here) that on top of the caulking areas exposed to water (in this case, my kitchen sink), a sealant should be applied.

Is this standard procedure? If so, are there different types that I need to consider? Any particular suggestions (to a specific product) would be helpful too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never heard of this recommendation. If you are caulking an area that will regularly be exposed to water (sink, shower, etc.) I use a silicone caulk.  Silicone caulk is 100% waterproof so there is no need to add any extra sort of sealer.

Answer (score 4):

Caulking should be sealing.  If it isn't you are using the wrong kind of caulk or your area was prepped wrong.

The question is like asking if you need to put an extra coat on if it is cold outside.